# In postgres function how to return a value from exception block in postgres command prompt

Tags: postgresql-9.5

how to catch exception when there is an error in query in postgre sql command prompt.The command prompt is stopped abnormally

```
 drop function udf_4();

    create or replace function udf_4()
    returns text as
    $body$
    DECLARE
    ename text;
    enumber text;
    etext text;
    cnt int;

    begin

       insert into employee values(1,'Mak');

    /*select count(*) into cnt from employee;
    if (cnt =0)
    then 

    return -10;

    end if;
        update employee set id = 99 where name = 'Mak';

        return 0;*/

        exception 
        when others then
            ename=SQLERRM;
            enumber=SQLSTATE;
            etext=ename || ':' ||enumber;
            return etext ;

    end;
    $body$
    language plpgsql;
```

please find a way to resolve

Comment: table does not present in database so it has to go to exception block

Comment: GUI it works but in postgre sql command prompt not working ??